# aspx file extension not showing, and I get a 404........weird

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to grok this behavior and get some resolution on this, so stay with me without laughing too much.  I know this is going to sound dumb.

I've got a page in one directory.  we'll call it SearchForm.aspx.  We are currently going through an upgrade of an application.  If a request comes through for the url "SearchForm?parameter=value", I'd like it to redirect to another directory to the new SearchForm page with the query string.  I've written a new asp .net webforms app that all it does is handle redirects.  It has a new web.config as shown below.  With the new redirect webforms app, the app doesn't want to process my "SearchForm?parameter=value" web request.  It will work if I use "SearchForm.aspx?Parameter=value" and it does what I want.  I am thinking that there is something in the web.config that I need to set to get the new redirect web app to do processing without the file extensions.  What in the heck is that?  My existing app works and doesn't show the file extensions in a page request, but the new redirect web app doesn't want to actually hand the request to the searchform file without the .aspx request, which is really strange to me.  Any suggestions on how to fix this are appreciated.  TIA.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you looked at rewrite module?

Comment: Do you have "friendly" urls's installed and setup on that new project? By default, all web pages MUST include the .aspx extension. However, you can setup what are called "friendly" url's, and that allows use of the page without the aspx file extension. it also allows one to use the "/" for parameter's. Want an example of a friendly url with a "/" style parameter? Why of course this VERY web page you are looking at (jstack overflow is written in asp.net net!!!). So the /questions, and /number, and /aspx-file-extension-notshowing.... don't exist as URL's - they are parameters.

Comment: You can install + setup friendly URL's via nuget if you wish.

Comment: I had just setup a brand new empty webforms project.  When I went back and setup a webforms project, not empty, things seemed to work better.  I believe the difference was in one of the optimization assemblies that is not included in the empty project.  Thank you.

Comment: No, if you create a empty project, then friendly URL's are not setup and installed for you. If you create a web site project, then the menus and by default friendly URL's are installed and setup by default. So, of course one way to get/have/enjoy and use friendly URL's is to create a project (not empty), and it will be setup for you.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks, yes, that is what I did.  I couldn't think of the term "friendly urls" so that was causing me mental strain.  :-)

Comment: yes, often the issue is the "term" As noted, friendly url's are  great feature, and as noted, StackOverflow is written in asp.net, and you can see use of that feature by looking at the url of this post! - they actually don't exist but in fact are a base URL with parameter's that "look" like a static URL. Anyway, no problem. It is still good to know the term, and also that you can install friendly url's via nuget. In fact, the painfully part is how to turn them off in the rare case you wish to do so. All good - good luck.